# who were the first known people to play a reed instrument

Tags: instruments, history, reeds

I would like to know who the first people to come up with the idea of reed instruments of any kind

Comment: You have a good question, but seeing as the answer is in the usual obvious places, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-reed_instrument , why are you asking here?

Comment: I am clearing the 4 inappropriate close votes here. Do not make up close reasons due to dislike of the question, just downvote. Please take further discussion to [Meta].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, people in the outdoors with leisure time.  Now outdoor jobs in prehistoric times were not all that unusual, but leisure time may have been.  Hunters might have started reed instruments from primitive bird calls.  Shepherds are obvious candidates for perfecting those in leisure time, and are also associated with ancient flutes.  [Shawms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shawm) are medieval instruments but have antique predecessors: Egypt with its papyrus-grounded culture would be an obvious candidate for pre-antique versions of reed instruments.

Comment: Sources for any of this?  Comes across as speculation and postulation.

Answer (score -1):

This is more of an archaeology question than a music question, but it is generally agreed upon by the scientific community that the oldest known instruments are paleolithic-era bone flutes dating back to at least 42,000 years ago. As flutes are a type of reed instrument, this should answer your question!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleolithic_flutes

http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-18196349

Comment: @ I dont consider the flute as reed instrument. Even if a pan flute is made of reed, it does not fit the definition of being involved in sound wave production.

Comment: @guidot I wasn't talking about the pan flute at all -- from a physical perspective, the flute is considered a reed instrument (by the professionals that play it, at least) because it requires splitting an airstream with a sharp edge. Strictly speaking it's not in the Hornbostel-Sachs 422 classification, but the physical mechanism is fundamentally the same.

Comment: Seems clear to me that the op isn't asking about air reeds.

Comment: Whatever dudes; 42,000-year-old bone flutes from the upper Paleolithic are freaking cool and worth talking about. Gimme dem downvotes